# Code completion plugin for sublime

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am working on an in house JavaScript framework of my employer. The developers use either Eclipse/ STS or sublime text to code. I wanted to develop a code completion plugin for either of the above, which will provide code completion support for our framework APIs. Could someone provide me a few pointers or  directions on how should I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [tern.js](http://ternjs.net/). It already has an [Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Eclipse-IDE) as well as [Sublime plugin](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_sublime).

There is some support in tern to provide and generate definitions for APIs. Look at condense tool described in the docs. However even without it, completion in your project just might work. Give it a try.